# Unconfigured data when exporting to csv file

Tags: php, mysql, shopware

I'm trying to export shopware 6 products in a csv file using php, but the data is coming unconfigured, I can't read it.
the main idea is to export just 4 columns and relate the data, initially I'm trying to export everything, and then check the product with its variables and price.
below the code and the result:

[image]

```
<?php


// Create headers:
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=produtos.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

// Create file out produtos.csv:
$saida = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// Placing columns in the file produtos.csv:
$colunas = 'id, product_number, tax_id, product_translation_name';
fputcsv($saida, array($colunas));

// Getting the data from the database:
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
$table = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$conn->query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
$conn->query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
$conn->query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

// Searching all columns
$linhas = "select" .
"       x.product_id" .
"       , x.product_number" .
"       , x.tax_id" .
"       , x.price_netto" .
"       , x.product_translation_name" .
"       , x.product_property_name" .
" from" .
"   (" .
"       select" .
"           b.product_id" .
"           , a.product_number" .
"           , a.tax_id" .
"           , a.price as price_netto" .
"           , b.name as product_translation_name" .
"           , null as product_property_name" .
"           , 1 as ordem" .
"       from" .
"           dev_ashop_1.product a" .
"           inner join dev_ashop_1.product_translation b on b.product_id = a.id" .
"       union all" .
"       select" .
"           b.product_id" .
"           , a.product_number" .
"           , a.tax_id" .
"           , a.price as price_netto" .
"           , b.name as product_translation_name" .
"           , d.name as product_property_name" .
"           , 2 as ordem" .
"       from" .
"           dev_ashop_1.product a" .
"           inner join dev_ashop_1.product_translation b on b.product_id = a.id" .
"           inner join dev_ashop_1.product_option c on c.product_id = a.id" .
"           inner join dev_ashop_1.property_group_option_translation d on d.property_group_option_id = c.property_group_option_id" .
"   ) x" .
" order by" .
"   x.product_id" .
"   , x.product_number" .
"   , x.ordem";



$result = $conn->query($linhas);

// Checking for data:
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Saida de dados por um array:
  while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Inserindo os dados no arquivo produtos.csv:
    fputcsv($saida, $linha);
  }
} else {
  echo "";
}
$conn->close();

// close
fclose($saida);

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with unconfigured? I can recommend you to use LibreOffice to read CSV files. There choose the correct encoding and delimiter.

Comment: _I'm trying to export shopware 6 products in a csv file_ Then show us the code that you wrote to do this

Comment: I edited the question and inserted the code

Comment: The data is JSON so you probably need to decode it first.  Then there will be other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple problems here:

1. The CSV header you write with `fputcsv($saida, array($colunas));` does not  correspond to the actual columns you are printing. In output you have a price JSON, in the header you don't mention the price. And it would be better if you make `$colunas` an array with the columns as items, not the full string.
2. The price is in JSON format. You might want to use `json_decode()` to extract the price data to single columns before writing it to the CSV.
3. You are opening the CSV in excel in the wrong way, check this: https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel, or better use LibreOffice which is better to read CSV files.

Comment: hello, thank you very much for taking your time, could you give me an example of how I would solve these problems?

Comment: I gave you already hints in the points, did you try those? do you have a specific question?

Comment: Show me some of that gibberish in _text_ not _image_.  That way, I can analyze it and might have a simple solution for you.